# trouble GROUPing rows in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have a table `myTable`

```
id  | test_id_1 | test_id_2  
001 | 0         | 1  
001 | 1         | 0  
002 | 1         | 0  
002 | 0         | 1  
003 | 1         | 0  
003 | 0         | 1
```

And I'm trying to group the rows based on `id` so that I can get single rows with the `id` like such

```
 id | test_id_1 | test_id_2  
001 | 1         | 1    
002 | 1         | 1    
003 | 1         | 1
```

This is my query

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
GROUP BY id
```

I keep getting an error saying that test_id_1 is not in the `GROUP BY`. But if I do include it I don't get the table I am looking for.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (I assume what you need is the sum of test_id_1 and test_id_2):

```
SELECT id, SUM(TEST_ID_1), SUM(TEST_ID_2)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY id
```

The group by syntax requires you to aggregate all the columns are not listed in "group by" clause, and that is the reason you got error. By speaking of aggregation, you can use SUM, COUNT, MAX OR MIN functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the same output, while you go for maximum value of test_id_1 and test_id_2  for each id wise group. So you can try the below query also

```
SELECT id, MAX(TEST_ID_1), MAX(TEST_ID_2)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY id
```